# Autofilter - Filtering data and copying into a specific row, then changing a filter and copying into a row below the first set

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am creating an Excel workbook that will use VBA to apply two filters to a sheet of requested items. Column Q contains either 'Hardware' or 'Smartphone', Column R contains either 'Yes' or 'No'. The contents of the other fields don't matter. A filter will be applied to Column Q for 'Hardware' and Column R for 'No'. For each item which meets both criteria, they will be pasted into a specific row, A11, on another tab which contains a header row in A10. Below the rows that have been pasted in, I'd like two blank rows, then a line of text "Your Text Here", and the header row will be repeated. Lastly the Column R filter will be switched to 'Yes' with the Column Q filter staying on 'Hardware'. The rows produced by this filter will be copied in below this second header row.

The Hardware tab will then contain the following,

- A1-A9 - Blank, the contents will be added later.
- A10 - Header row for the data,
- A11-A(X) - Data rows with Column Q = "Hardware" and Column R = "No",
- A(X+1)-A(X+2) - Blank rows,
- A(X+3) - "Your Text Here",
- A(X+4) - Header row for the data,
- A(X+5) - Data rows with Column Q = "Hardware" and Column R = "Yes".

I have adapted a VBA script which I found here on this site, many thanks to Siddharth Rout.
[How to copy a line in excel using a specific word and pasting to another excel sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)

When I run the macro, it applies the two filters correctly and copies the correct rows into the 'Hardware' tab. However I want it to be pasted into Cell A11 below the header row, but the data is actually overwriting this and copying into Cell A10.

Because I can't stop overwriting my header row or get the first set in the right place, I'm not sure how to then add what I need below it as well as how to determine where the second set will go.

I have tried changing the value in 'After:=.Range("A11"), _' but I am quite possibly misunderstanding what it does. I want it to always go in starting at row A11 and not touch anything in rows 10 and above even if they are blank.

```
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Raw")

   With ws1

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("Q1:R" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Hardware" '-> Hardware Items
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="No" '-> Not Business Continuity
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '-> Destination
    Set ws2 = wb1.Worksheets("Hardware")

    With ws2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A11"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With

    wb1.Save
End Sub
```

Many thanks to anyone who may respond and apologies if my summary could be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that you have to paste the range in A11, you can directly paste it there.
Instead of using find for lrow ,inside the With ws2 do

```
With ws2
        copyFrom.Copy .Range("A11")
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

This will paste the range in row A11 then you can get the next last row . Get X by  (define it as Dim lrow as Long).

Now you have the lastrow that contains data (X). As you stated the next data row is X + 5 . First clear the initial filter by

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

So adjust the code to do the other filter with criteria "Yes" and then paste it by

```
 With ws2
         copyFrom.Copy .Range("A" & lrow + 5)
```

Comment: Ah! Brilliant, thanks!
I now have the first data set being copied into the correct place, the second set being added 5 rows below the final line, and some additional lines in the script to add a header row and some text into one of the cells.

Comment: Good to hear! Good luck on your project.